# how to remove u' and ' from tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

i saw that this question already been asked but the solutions i saw didn't worked for me.

i have a python script with tuple list which i want to retrieve without the unicode char (u') and without any other chars (like < [] > or < ' >) so only the data will pass to parameter.

my code look like this -

```
sql_cursor = con.cursor()
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(get_alerted_ip)
Results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in Results:
    ip_to_open.append(row)
    print (row)
con.close()
```

the output is -

```
(u'172.1.1.124',)
```

and the wanted output should look like -

```
172.1.1.124
```

I have already tried to convert the tuple to list or string in order to use methods like replace but it's not working.

what am i doing wrong? please help.

Comment: The output is a one-tuple (`(`, `,`, `)`), containing a Unicode string (`u`, `'`, `'`). If you want just the string, then **access the first element of that tuple**. You don't want to *"remove u' and ' from tuple list"*, not least because you don't have a *"tuple list"*.

Comment: In 2018 you should seriously consider switching to Python 3

Comment: you absolutely correct and i already work with but this is an old legacy that i need to maintained. 
anyway, thank you it was helpful

Comment: it is not a problem ! ignore that

Comment: you can use str(row[0]) which will be giving you the string version removing the Unicode character

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
row[0].encode("utf-8")
```

will return the ascii version of the string